# How to get expressions from FreeMarker template

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

I have FreeMarker template with some expressions like ${name}, ${company}, ${price}, etc..

In my java app I have to do list or array with every expression name what is in template.
Is there any way to do it ?

Thanks for intressting.

Comment: Your question is a little vague.  Are you trying to list all available variables in the model?  Are you trying to list every variable used in the template after the template is processed?  I'm curious, what is the need to do any of this?

Answer (score 0):

You must provide values for these variables in the Freemarker execution context. You can do this either by passing named values (ie a Map) when you call it, or you can access java classes directly from within the template and get values from static/factory methods or whatever, or you can invoke custom TemplateMethodModel methods and invoking them.

For example:

```
<#assign name=getNameMethod() />
```

Read up on the web - it's a big subject.